# Изменить местоположение UIIimage

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Друзья, помогите, пожалуйста. Суть вопроса в следующем: есть 9 UIImage, на каждой UIImage есть свой UILable. UIImage и UILable  расположены в строго определенных местах (типа как в игре крестики-нолики, т. е. получается квадрат из 9 картинок 3x3). Так вот, при нажатии на кнопку эти UIImage должны перемешаться в случайном порядке и отобразиться на новых местах, но в пределах первоначального расположения, т. е. должен получиться новый квадарат 3х3. Вроде понятно написал.

За ранее всем огромное спасибо.

P.S.: в принципе я сделал это, но через одно место (как мне кажется). Оч надо ваше мнение.

```
//  Создаём массив с координатами каждого из 9 "черных" квадратов.
NSMutableArray * SquareArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare1.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare2.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare3.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare4.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare5.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare6.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare7.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare8.center]];
[SquareArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:BlackSquare9.center]];

for (int i = 0; i < [SquareArray count]; ++i) {
    int r = (random() % [SquareArray count]);
    [SquareArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:r];

}

NSString *coordinaty1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:0]];
NSString *coordinaty2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:1]];
NSString *coordinaty3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:2]];
NSString *coordinaty4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:3]];
NSString *coordinaty5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:4]];
NSString *coordinaty6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:5]];
NSString *coordinaty7 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:6]];
NSString *coordinaty8 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:7]];
NSString *coordinaty9 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[SquareArray objectAtIndex:8]];

BlackSquare1.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty1);
BlackSquareLabel1.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty1);
BlackSquare2.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty2);
 BlackSquareLabel2.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty2);
BlackSquare3.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty3);
 BlackSquareLabel3.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty3);
BlackSquare4.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty4);
 BlackSquareLabel4.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty4);
BlackSquare5.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty5);
 BlackSquareLabel5.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty5);
BlackSquare6.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty6);
 BlackSquareLabel6.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty6);
BlackSquare7.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty7);
 BlackSquareLabel7.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty7);
BlackSquare8.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty8);
 BlackSquareLabel8.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty8);
BlackSquare9.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty9);
 BlackSquareLabel9.center = CGPointFromString(coordinaty9);
```

Comment: @Maestas, Добавьте ваш код и уточните, в каким именно местах вы считаете его не правильным.

Comment: Код добавил. Я не считаю, что он не правильный (работает же :) ). Просто есть ощущение, что это можно реализовать более проще.

Answer (score 1):

зачем менять местоположение элементов? Почему просто не сетить новые картинки в нужные `UIImageView` и `UILabel`?

к тому же вы можете отрисовывать нужные картинки и текст в нужных местах в **drawRect**, например:

```
NSArray *objects = @[@{@"frame": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectZero], @"imageName": @"someImage.png", @"text": NSLocalizedString(@"some text", @"")} /* etc...*/];

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect *)rect {
    NSDictionary *textAttributes = @{/*Some text attributes here*/}
    for (NSDictionary *object in objects) {
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:object[@"imageName"]];
          NSString *text = object[@"text"];
          CGRect iconFrame = [object[@"frame"] CGRectValue];
          [image drawInRect:iconFrame];
          [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(iconFrame.origin.x, iconFrame.origin.y + iconFrame.size.height, 20.0, iconFrame.size.width) withAttributes:textAttributes];
    }
}
```

Comment: Задача стоит именно так:
Сначала появляется экран с 9 пустыми квадратами (UIImage) и в каждом квадрате написан номер (UILable). Нижний ряд 1 2 3, средний 4 5 6, верхний 7 8 9. Далее пользователь нажимает кнопку и с анимацией эти квадраты перемещаются на новые СЛУЧАЙНЫЕ места. А заполнение этих квадратов картинками происходит уже потом.